# Using ntile based on the amount of records in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am wondering if there is a solution to my question.

I have a list of markers. I use ntile and separate each record in the result set amongst markers.

```
SELECT id, 
       type,  
       CASE
         WHEN ntile(3) OVER(ORDER BY id) = 1 THEN 'Marker 1 blah dfg'
         WHEN ntile(3) OVER(ORDER BY id) = 2 THEN 'Marker 2 blah sdf dfg'
         WHEN ntile(3) OVER(ORDER BY id) = 3 THEN 'Marker 3 blah ad asa'
         ELSE 'OTHER'
       END AS Marker
 FROM TABLE1
```

How can I implement it with a table and obtain a list of markers from there dynamically instead of hard typing them as shown above?

I need to implement similar :

```
ntile(Select COUNT(*) from MARKERS_TABLE) OVER(ORDER BY id) = [MARKERS_TABLE.MARKER_RECORD_ID]
     THEN [MARKERS_TABLE.CORRESPONDING_MARKER_DESCRIPTION]
```

but how do I loop over 1, 2 and 3...*n* ? And How do I assign corresponding values in the above scenario?

**MARKERS_TABLE**

MARKER_RECORD_ID| CORRESPONDING_MARKER_DESCRIPTION

**TABLE1**

ID | TYPE | CASE |

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results (by editing the question)?

Comment: Put the markers in a table, add an id column 1,2,3,... and then join to it

Comment: @dnoeth, OK, I joined the table. So what is then? How do I create a dynamic case like I have in the example above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must pass a constant to NTILE, so a scalar subquery doesn't work:

```
select t.val, m.value
from 
 (
   select val, 
      ntile(3) over (order by t.val) as ntile
   from t
 ) t 
join markers m
on m.id = t.ntile;
```

Of course you could pass the count as a parameter using PL/SQL.

If you really need the count dynamically in pure SQL there's a workaround, although it's less efficient, see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ab18/20):

```
with cte(n) as
  (select count(*) from markers)
select t.val, m.value
from 
 (
   select val, 
      ntile(cte.n) over (partition by cte.n order by t.val) as ntile
   from t, cte
 ) t 
join markers m
on m.id = t.ntile
;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
merge
   into TABLE1 d
   using (
      select ID, MARKER_DESC
      from (select 
              t1.ID,
              ntile(count(0)) over(order by t1.ID) as marker_id
            from TABLE1 t1, MARKERS_TABLE
            group by t1.ID) 
      left join MARKERS_TABLE using (marker_id)
   ) s
   on (d.ID = s.ID)
when matched then update set
   MARKER = s.MARKER_DESC;
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4a187/1)

Comment: Of course this results in a cross join between both tables before the GROUP BY, so hopefully the OP doesn't have too many markers :-)